# Remove .php from URL and force a trailing slash /

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want to use `.htaccess` `mod_rewrite` to remove `.php` from all my files and force a trailing slash /. However, it is only resulting in me getting server errors.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4026021/remove-php-extension-with-htaccess

Answer (score 2):

You want to map :

```
http://sampledomain.ext/index/ -> http://sampledomain.ext/index.html
```

Use the following .htaccess

```
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ! \.php$ #Avoid real php page, do what you want with them
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /$       #Ensure a final slash
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php           #Add your extension
```

Tx to David Wolever who write quitely the same stuff [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5745490/rewrite-rule-to-add-html-extension)

If I can give my opinion, it's a little bit strange to force the / at the end for a file no?