# How to make a webpage without .html in your URL

Tags: apache, xhtml, html, server

Like the title says I want to visit my webpage without typing .html after the webadres.
So for example I have to type this at the moment: www.webadres.com/webpage.html
Now I want to change that into www.webadres.com/webpage

I've already tried some things like deleting the .html extension on the end of my file but that (of course) doesn't work.

I see I missed something:
I don't really understand it but I got a folder (called "cgi-bin") with a .htacces file.
In the .htacces file is the following text:

> Options -Indexes +ExecCGI AddHandler cgi-script .cgi .pl

I want a webpage like this

```
www.example.com/webpage
```

Instead of

```
www.example.com/webpage.html
```

I didn't know about all the server side technologies but now it seems I have Apache.

If it didn't worked out you could also check out these:
[How to remove .html from URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5730092/how-to-remove-html-from-url)
[ReWrite rule to add .html extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5745490/rewrite-rule-to-add-html-extension)

Comment: What server are you using?

Comment: This is usually a server side feature. What kind of web server technology are you using? ASP.NET / PHP?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to remove .html from URL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5730092/how-to-remove-html-from-url)

Comment: [URL Rewriting](https://www.addedbytes.com/articles/for-beginners/url-rewriting-for-beginners/)

Comment: @DavidePastore: Depends on the server side technology used. So too early to say.

Comment: go this topic
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5745490/rewrite-rule-to-add-html-extension

Comment: @PatrickHofman: You're right. :D

Answer (score -2, accepted):

create a htaccess file which has the name of .htaccess, then place the following code

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^yourPage$ yourPage.html [NC,L]
```

Comment: How do you know what server side technology OP uses?

Comment: The most of the people solve this problem like this

Comment: I have never used this in ASP.NET.

Comment: Not if they don't use Apache.

Comment: You can't solve this without apache

Comment: You can. ASP.NET any many other technologies have similar solutions.

Comment: You realize there are many different web servers out there right?

Comment: Then comment it to another answer... I've used this, this's an easy way, it works me fine, and servers usually have apache

Comment: No, this question is much too broad and unanswerable. We shouldn't answer at all.