# How to enable/modify phpbb url to work just like html?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, phpbb3

I have installed `phpbb 3.1.4` newly.. Currently my web urls are like this http:// mydomain.com/**viewtopic.php?f=6&p=6#p6**
How can i force it to use 
http:// mydomain.com/**mytopics.html**

I have tried editing .htaccess but still its hope less..

My default htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on

#
# Uncomment the statement below if you want to make use of
# HTTP authentication and it does not already work.
# This could be required if you are for example using PHP via Apache CGI.
#
#RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization},L]

#
# The following 3 lines will rewrite URLs passed through the front controller
# to not require app.php in the actual URL. In other words, a controller is
# by default accessed at /app.php/my/controller, but can also be accessed at
# /my/controller
#
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ app.php [QSA,L]

#
# If symbolic links are not already being followed,
# uncomment the line below.
# http://anothersysadmin.wordpress.com/2008/06/10/mod_rewrite-forbidden-403-with-apache-228/
#
#Options +FollowSymLinks
</IfModule>

# With Apache 2.4 the "Order, Deny" syntax has been deprecated and moved from
# module mod_authz_host to a new module called mod_access_compat (which may be
# disabled) and a new "Require" syntax has been introduced to mod_authz_host.
# We could just conditionally provide both versions, but unfortunately Apache
# does not explicitly tell us its version if the module mod_version is not
# available. In this case, we check for the availability of module
# mod_authz_core (which should be on 2.4 or higher only) as a best guess.
<IfModule mod_version.c>
    <IfVersion < 2.4>
        <Files "config.php">
            Order Allow,Deny
            Deny from All
        </Files>
        <Files "common.php">
            Order Allow,Deny
            Deny from All
        </Files>
    </IfVersion>
    <IfVersion >= 2.4>
        <Files "config.php">
            Require all denied
        </Files>
        <Files "common.php">
            Require all denied
        </Files>
    </IfVersion>
</IfModule>
<IfModule !mod_version.c>
    <IfModule !mod_authz_core.c>
        <Files "config.php">
            Order Allow,Deny
            Deny from All
        </Files>
        <Files "common.php">
            Order Allow,Deny
            Deny from All
        </Files>
    </IfModule>
    <IfModule mod_authz_core.c>
        <Files "config.php">
            Require all denied
        </Files>
        <Files "common.php">
            Require all denied
        </Files>
    </IfModule>
</IfModule>
```

Please guide me, how to fix this?

Update : I have tried adding below in my htaccess .. No difference

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{3,4}
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.html
```

Above codes copy pasted from From [ReWrite rule to add .html extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5745490/rewrite-rule-to-add-html-extension)

And also tried  adding

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^.*.php$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.html [L,R=301]
```

and also tried adding ([Source](http://forum.powweb.com/archive/index.php/t-70095.html))

```
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^(.*)-f([0-9]*)/(.*)-t([0-9]*)-s([0-9]*).html viewtopic.php?f=$2&t=$4&start=$5&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)-f([0-9]*)/(.*)-t([0-9]*).html viewtopic.php?f=$2&t=$4&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
RewriteRule global/(.*)-t([0-9]*).html ./viewtopic.php?f=1&t=$2&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)-f([0-9]*)/index-s([0-9]*).html viewforum.php?f=$2&start=$3&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)-f([0-9]*)/ viewforum.php?f=$2&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)-f([0-9]*) viewforum.php?f=$2&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
RewriteRule ^forum.html index.php?%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
```

Comment: Exactly what have you tried so far?  What did it do?  How was that different from what you expected/wanted?

Comment: Hi Sorry for the delay in reply.. I have tried above code.. added after update section of the above question

Comment: All what i need is instead of viewtopic.php?f=6&p=6#p6 string put someting.html

Comment: For example phpbb-seo.com successfully added html for php bb http://www.phpbb-seo.com/en/phpbb-forum/article2371.html  .. Not sure they achived this html thing using htaccess or any other method

Comment: I have added all what i tried, yet no idea how to fix this , Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just wish to share this.. Looks like there is no way to do this using htaccess.. It was confirmed by KevC   - Support Team Member Phpbb

https://www.phpbb.com/community/viewtopic.php?f=466&t=2319241