# How to redirect to URLs WITH .html extension using .htaccess

Tags: html, .htaccess, redirect

All the URLs on my site use the .html extension. I'd like to make it so that any URLs that are entered into the browser **without** the .html extension are redirected to the URL **with** the .html extension.

In summary, I want this

```
http://example.com/page
```

to redirect to

```
http://example.com/page.html
```

I feel like this question had to have been asked before but I cannot seem to find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this rule in your root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^.]+?)/?$ /$1.html [L,R=302]
```

Comment: That almost works. It works for files in the root folder but it redirects all files in subfolders to the root folder. So `http://example.com/subfolder/page` redirects to `http://example.com/page.html`

Comment: That can happen only if your .htaccess is in `subfolder`.

Comment: Ohhh, I see. Okay so what if you host multiple sites and don't want all URLs to go to the version with the extension?

Comment: Nvm I just realized that site's that need the extension removed can have that specified within their folder and it will override the root. Thank you!

Comment: You should add your answer [over here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5745490/rewrite-rule-to-add-html-extension). Your solution worked for me and none of the answers mentioned there solved my problem.

Comment: Thanks, I will do that.