# How to change url php script htaccess methode

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting

How to change this url

http://domain.com/search/song

to

http://domain.com/search/song.html

.htaccess File

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On

# Redirect Trailing Slashes...
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*) index.php?/$1 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: If you guess the number I'm thinking of, I tell you one of many posibilities on how it can be done ..

Comment: I am Use search Engine http://domain.com/search/song Convert into  http://domain.com/search/song.html

Comment: change `RewriteRule ^(.*) index.php?/$1 [QSA,L] ` for `RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ index.php?/$1 [QSA,L]`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ReWrite rule to add .html extension](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5745490/rewrite-rule-to-add-html-extension)

Comment: Not Working I am try This Code

Comment: I have edited my answer below. Please try second solution.

Answer (score 2):

Try to add string

```
RewriteRule ^(/search/song)$ $1.html [L,R=301]
```

right after `RewriteEngine On`

If this doesn't work, try to put this:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^(/search/song)$ $1.html
```

This should work perfectly.

Comment: I edited your question to remove the leading slash from the Rule's pattern, leading slash is not allowed in htaccess context.