# htaccess 301 redirect to .html

Tags: php, .htaccess

I originally wanted my pages to work with and without the file extensions.

This is what my working htaccess looked like:

```
RewriteEngine On

# .php to .html
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /(.+)\.php[?\s] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1.html [L,R=301]

# don't need extension on the end
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [L]

RewriteRule ^(.+)\.html/?$ $1.php [L,NC]
```

I would like to reverse the above and force all pages to resolve to .html.  I would like to include 301 redirects for Google.

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine  on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```

For example, this will correctly rewrite `example.com/test` as a request for `example.com/test.php`

you can remove both php html extensions by the following code

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options +MultiViews
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
#RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)\/?$ $1.php [NC]


RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.html
#RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)\/?$ $1.html [NC]

</IfModule>
```