# How to remove .html from url using htaccess for a tomcat server

Tags: html, .htaccess, tomcat

My URL Is: `http://localhost:8080/home` not working.

**.htaccess is:**

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.html -f
RewriteRule .* http://localhost:8080/html/%1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.html [NC,L]
```

Comment: Could you be more clear on what exactly isn't working?

Comment: Also, localhost means nothing to us, as that is a web name that only has value to you. We can't see what's going on with it from here :D

Comment: If you want to automatically add `.html` to all requests, take a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5745490/rewrite-rule-to-add-html-extension