# Add .html extension at end of url after search

Tags: php, .htaccess

How add .html extension after search

url is like this : `www.domain.com/videos/searchname` to `www.domain.con/videos/searchname.html`
using `htaccess`

```
RewriteRule ^videos/(.+).html$ main-search.php?q=$1
RewriteRule ^view/(.+).html$ download.php?v=$1
RewriteRule ^download/(.+) hdbuddydown.php?v=$1
```

Comment: read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5745490/rewrite-rule-to-add-html-extension)

Comment: no its different

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ReWrite rule to add .html extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5745490/rewrite-rule-to-add-html-extension)

Comment: search video work by using main-search.php